# Oracle Order by array index

Tags: oracle, plsql

I have a collection which is a table of numbers containing primary keys and I want to sort a select statement - containing those keys - by the index of the number collection.
For example:

```sql
TYPE "NUMBERCOLLECTION" AS TABLE OF NUMBER;
...
myNumberCollection numberCollection := numberCollection(45, 7799, 2187);
...
select nr
     , columnA
     , columnB
  from myTable
 where myTable.nr member of myNumberCollection
 order by index of myNumberCollection
```

will result in

```
NR      COLUMNA COLUMNB
-----------------------
45      xyz     abc
7799    xyz     abc
2187    xyz     abc
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
SELECT nr,
       columnA,
       columnB
FROM   myTable m
       INNER JOIN
       ( SELECT ROWNUM AS id, COLUMN_VALUE FROM TABLE( myNumberCollection ) ) c
       ON ( m.nr = c.COLUMN_VALUE )
ORDER BY c.id;
```